# Nvme not showing up in /dev on Ubuntu 19.04 (5.0.0-13)

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules, block-device, nvme, character-device

I have an Ubuntu 19.04 on a machine with an nvme drive. However, the drive is not found in `/dev/nvme*`. `cat /proc/devices` shows that nvme is loaded as a character device and not a block device and `lsmod` shows two loaded modules *nvme* and *nvme_core*. Any help on what is wrong here or how to debug would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the following link is related: [18.04 or 19.04 on Samsung NVMe SSD → Bus errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176021/18-04-or-19-04-on-samsung-nvme-ssd-%e2%86%92-bus-errors)

Comment: There was a now deleted answer by @RingØ, "

tl;dr if that can help:

Replaced the M.2 NVMe Samsung Evo Plus with a M.2 NVMe Western Digital "Black SN750" 500GB.

Installed also a 2nd M.2 NVMe, SanDisk Extreme Pro.

And Ubuntu just works, with both new M.2 drives, without any kernel adjustment.

Spent quite some time on this ; after reading forums about NVMe integration in Linux, it appears that the Samsung drives do not seem Linux friendly."

Comment: I can add that I have an nvme drive, a Kingston A2000 250GB M.2 2280 PCI Express 3.0 x4 (NVMe). It is seen by `lsblk -o model` as `KINGSTON SA2000M8250G`. I tested that it can be seen not only by 18.04.1 LTS and Focal Fossa, but also by 19.04, so your problem might depend on the nvme drive itself and lack of compatibility with Ubuntu and/or linux (and not on specific problems with 19.04).

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for your help, I will try a different NVMe and update the post.

Comment: @sudodus I decided to delete the answer because after a while the WD drive showed the same problems, much less than Samsung, more erratically, but of course I can't keep using such an unstable system. So I installed a classic SSD (Samsung!) and it works well. The WD symptoms were similar to using the Samsung (again, much less). I don't think the MB or the BIOS were the culprit. Linux still not ready for (new) NVMe drives, maybe ....

Comment: @RingØ, I am testing an nvme drive, but only running it sporatically. I have not yet found any issue, but I will certainly check for problems like you describe. Have you considered also the hardware connecting the nvme drive and the motherboard? Have you any experience of running Windows on your mvme drive?

Comment: @sudosus relevant questions indeed. The MB is Asus Z390-F and the 2 drives are part of the MB. Using Windows for a day (just installed and run scripts), none of the 2 drives I've tested had any problem! I see your Kingston is OK. Have a SanDisk NVMe on an Asus laptop (Ubuntu 18.04) => No pb. It seems those Samsung and the like use proprietary crap drivers that's only provided to MS...

Comment: @RingØ, I think you are right about that.